# Does using IfModifiedSince access condition reduce the number of Azure Blob Storage transactions?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

There's [`BlobRequestOptions.AccessCondition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobrequestoptions.accesscondition) property that can be set to [`IfModifiedSince`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.accesscondition.ifmodifiedsince) so that for example `ListBlobs()` returns only the blobs modified after specified time.

Now the description for [ListBlobs REST API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) doesn't have any parameters onto which that access condition could be mapped. So I assume that all the blobs will be returned and then the StorageClient code will programmatically filter them on the client.

So it looks like using the access condition doesn't change the number of requests to the Storage.

Do access conditions actually reduce the number of transactions or are they only applied on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `BlobRequestOptions` object can be passed as a parameter to all functions in Storage Client library, please note that `AccessCondition` is only applicable to a few operations. For a list of operations where you could specify `AccessCondition`, please see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179371.aspx#Subheading2. For all other operations, `AccessCondition` parameter will be ignored.

Specifically `ListBlobs()` ignores `AccessCondition`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasted so much time on trying to figure this out.